# jQuery Flexslider plugin not working in Phonegap iOS app

Tags: jquery, ios, xcode, cordova, flexslider

Is it possible to have an image gallery slider in xcode when developing using phone gap?

I have put in some jquery code which runs fine in a browser but not in my ios simulator.

```
    <title>Test App</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexslider.css" />
</head>
<body><h1>Test App</h1>
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="img/cordova.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img/cordova.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img/cordova.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="img/cordova.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
                       $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                                                   animation: "slide",
                                                   start: function(slider){
                                                   $('body').removeClass('loading');
                                                   }
                                                   });
                       });
        </script>
        </body>
```

Will that work in phone gap cordova?

Comment: Perhaps describe the problem you are seeing in the iOS simulator?   Some jQuery plugins won't work that well for mobile browsers, because of touch vs click events, differences in scrolling, etc. FWIW, I've used this image gallery plugin on a mobile browser and it worked pretty well: http://www.photoswipe.com

Comment: @asgeo1 I get no error but my image doesnt show

Comment: Please post the rest of your source code as well...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a problem with how you're using the Flexslider plugin. The doco for flexslider suggests it works on mobile browsers. I can't think of any reason why it would behave differently in a phonegap app, so I would assume you are doing something wrong.

Phonegap is not the best at showing javascript errors. Just because you're not seeing any in the Xcode console doesn't mean there aren't any.

I find the best way to debug Phonegap apps these days is to use desktop Safari on OSX.

Under the Develop menu in Safari, you should be able to open the developer tools to inspect the phonegap app running in the iOS simulator. You can also target a connected iPhone device if you want too.

Unfortunately the console in the dev tools will only pick up JS errors that occur after you've opened it, so you may need to trigger your JS code manually after the tools have opened.

You should also be able to use the dev tools to see the `<img>` tags. This will give you a clue as to whether they are there, but just not visible. Perhaps some sort of CSS problem, etc.